# SATA Blu-Ray drive not detected via USB adapter

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, blu-ray

I'm using an SATA blu-ray drive (Lite-On IHOS104), connected via a USB adapter to my Windows 7 (32-bit) notebook.

The first time I plugged the adapter in, it worked perfectly. The drive appeared in Explorer, and my player software was able to play an encrypted Blu-Ray disc just fine.

After the first reboot, it never worked again. Now it shows up as "removable media" with a size of 0 bytes, irregardless of whether a disk is inserted or not. The drive does not show up under the green "eject USB device" icon in the taskbar. The adapter is powered using a separate power adapter.

I have tried:

- disconnecting all other USB devices
- testing with a DVD instead of a Blu-Ray disc
- letting Windows search for updated drivers for the drive - there are none
- using the same drive and adapter on another Win7 (but x64) computer. They work perfectly.
- using other USB ports on the same notebook - tried them all.
- using a different SATA/USB-adapter

What else can I do to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Can you return it for an exchange?  You may have an infant mortality.

Comment: The drive has been used for several years and works just fine when connected to the SATA port of a desktop PC. I have also tried it with another SATA/USB-Adapter, to no avail.